# submitting form in plain js doesn't triggers events attached by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have the code like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("#main_form").submit(function(){
            alert("submitting");
        });

        $("#main_form").on("submit", function(){
            alert("ON submitting");
        });


        $("#lnk").click(function(){
            //$("#main_form").submit(); //when submitting like this - event is triggered
            document.getElementById("main_form").submit();  //no submitting alerts are triggered
        });
    });
</script>

<h4><?php echo time(); ?></h4>

<form id="main_form" action="">
    <input type="text" value="x"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit-btn"/>
</form>

<a id="lnk" href="#">test submit js</a>
```

When I click submit button I have 2 alerts rising, so the onsubmit events are triggered but when I click link #lnk which have to submit from in plain js like

```
 document.getElementById("main_form").submit();
```

I get only form submition but without alerts.
But when I uncomment the submitting via jquery

```
$("#main_form").submit();
```

the alerts are back again.
Could anybody explain me why is that?

PS
I have legacy code which submits the form in plain js and I'd prefer not to change it, so I decided just to bind onsubmit events and perform some checkings in custom function but I've gotten a problem like described above

Answer (score 3):

Browsers do not fire the element's onsubmit event when the submit() method is called. When you use `jQuery().trigger("submit")` jQuery is calling the native `submit()` method for you but since it doesn't "see" the native event and the native `submit()` doesn't trigger the native onsubmit, it is not called. However, this is a browser quirk and outside the scope of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact events are called only when we have the iteraction from the user which means that **they cannot be invoked automatically when they are activated from the code.**

By the way, the following pieces of code are the same:

```
$("#main_form").submit(function(){
    alert("submitting");
});

$("#main_form").on("submit", function(){
    alert("ON submitting");
});
```

They are both fired when `submit` event occurs.

You can check this: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.submit

Comment: >>  they cannot be invoked automatically when they are activated from the code. | But this $("#main_form").submit(); rises events instead of document.getElementById("main_form").submit();